# Install haskell koans on windows

Tags: haskell

I am trying to learn haskell using haskell koans https://github.com/HaskVan/HaskellKoans. The installation instructions found is not working and they look presumably for linux. I need help to get the koans working on windows.

Comment: this is not a question

Comment: @RomanMik while yes it is not technical a question from the SO-book it might be usefull for other Haskell beginners trying to use those as well, and Balaji seems to just have joined here - so please keep it friendly and explain the problem (I am a really glad that the Haskell tag here still is :D - no need to get to the point where C# and co are)

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the top of [`setup-koans`](https://github.com/HaskVan/HaskellKoans/blob/master/bin/setup-koans), you'll see:

```
#!/usr/bin/env runhaskell
import Control.Monad (unless)
...etc
```

That first line with the [hashbang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) indicates that a unix shell running this file as a program should pass everything that follows (the haskell source file, in this case) to the command specified (`/usr/bin/env runhaskell` in this case).

If you have a GHC installation, and `runghc` in your path, you should be able to remove that line and do `runghc setup-koans`.

You might also like to play with cygwin, or with a linux virtual machine (e.g. in docker) to familiarize yourself with this sort of thing.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.I tried to get it work as you have suggested and it started to build. Cabal reported an error when it was downloading package hint. A similar issue was also reported here https://github.com/HaskVan/HaskellKoans/issues/9.